# Logging in classes - Python

Tags: python, class, logging

I'm trying to use Python's `logging` module, and have questions on the best way to use it.

I define several classes, want to write logs and be able to set the level of all of them at the same time. I tried :

- to use the same logger everywhere. But my classes are used by a framework, I don't have a single entrypoint where I could define a main logger. If so, how should I create it and add handlers ?
- to use one logger per file. Should I create it as a class attribute, and adding handlers only the first time the class is instantiated ? Or put it with the imports before the class definition ? [This tutorial](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/) told me not to, but I don't really get why.

Thanks for any hints. I've found lots of docs on the basic way to use a logger, but not much on how to use it in classes.

EDIT: I don't think it's a duplicate of the link below. The accepted answer explains how to load the config in a main program, and then use it in all the modules. But what if I don't have a main program ? Where do I define it ?

Comment: Can't you create it where your classes are defined? And like you proposed in question #2, as a singleton?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library?

Comment: @seb-mtl Yeah I could, but it seems heavy because I have to put that same code to get the same logger in every class. Is it really the good practice ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but this explains how to let the user configure the logger. Here, the user is the framework and won't configure it, but I still want it

Comment: @akshat I don't think it's a duplicate. The accepted answer explains how to load the config in a main program, and then use it in all the modules. But what if I don't have a main program ? Where do I define it ?

Comment: @Mean-Street, check other answers, which are not main program based.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you create logger objects in separate files, but with the same name. They will share all the attributes. In fact, they are the same logger. The `logging` module also allow the creation of logger objects in a hierarchical order. For example, a logger with name *spam.mod2* is a sub logger of *spam* in which it takes on all of *spam*'s attributes, but can also be customized.

To put it into concrete example. I am going to create a simple project which has 2 modules: `mod1` and `mod2`. A common module `setup_logger` is used to create a single logger. Finally, I have a `main` module, which drives the whole system.

The `setup_logger` module will create a new logger object and name it *spam*. The code can be simple as listed, or as complex as you want.

```
# setup_logger.py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('spam')
```

Next, `mod1` being lazy, just reuse that logger object:

```
# mod1.py
from setup_logger import logger

class Class1(object):
    def do_something(self):
        logger.info('Class1: doing something')
```

`mod2` creates its own logger object, but still need to import `setup_logger` so that the *spam* logger is created. `mod2` creates a sub logger by naming it *spam.mod2*:

```
# mod2.py
import logging
import setup_logger

# mod2 creates its own logger, as a sub logger to 'spam'
logger = logging.getLogger('spam.mod2')

class Class2:
    def do_something(self):
        logger.info('Class2: doing something')
```

Finally, `main` will put all of them together:

```
# main.py
import mod1
import mod2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    object1 = mod1.Class1()
    object1.do_something()

    object2 = mod2.Class2()
    object2.do_something()
```

Output:

```
INFO:spam:Class1: doing something
INFO:spam.mod2:Class2: doing something
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I define handlers to my logger in your `setup_logger.py`, and then import this several times (in each module), the handlers will be created each time the file is imported, right ? Isn't it a problem ?

Comment: The way Python works is the imported code only get executed once, no mater how many imports. Try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: The problem here is when `main.py` is invoked `mod1` gets imported which causes `setup_logger` to eventually be invoked before an instance of the class is ever instantiated. This is quite unflexible. One potential issue is how do you specify where log files go through a config file? In this setup before a config file can even be read the logger gets created.

Comment: @HaiVu thank you very much for this answer, it has helped me immensefully!